# Scrapy Crawl returning None

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm a Brazilian, so I'm sorry for bad English. I'm starting to learning python and how to use scrapy,  and I trying to get information from a table, but for some reasons the function that I wrote returning 'None', as you can see:

DEBUG: Scraped from <200 [https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>{'teste'](https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/%3E%7B%27teste%27): None}

It's returning 'None' with any class I try to put in the response.css. I also tried to get a text from other sites with the same code and it worked, so I'm guessing  it's something about this site specifically, but I really don't know. Could someone help me with these, please?

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "equipes"
    start_urls = ['https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'teste': response.css('tbody tr td.tablesaw-cell-persist').get()}
```

Comment: I’m not online via laptop to check that, are you sure it’s not a JS website ? Scrapy can’t render JS

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct. Data is generating dynamically with the help of javaScript. If you make disable javaScript from the browser and go to the dropdown list and try to change the table's name then you will see that it will never change like "CBLOL Split 1 2020" to "CBLOL Academy Split 2 2021" wouldn't change and this behavior is called dynamically populated by javaScript data changing  where as you didn't get data by grabbing static HTML. That's why you need headless browser to get data. Actually, we can't fix a technology to scrape a site rather than, a site shows us that what technology we have to use to scrape a site. Here I use `Selenium with Scrapy` which is also super fast like Scrapy Spider.

MY CODE:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from time import sleep


class TeamsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'teams'
    allowed_domains = ['gol.gg']
    start_urls = ['https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/']
   
    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
            #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        chrome_path = which("chromedriver")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)#, options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        self.driver.get("https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/")
        sleep(5)
        dropDown = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cbtournament"]/option[text()= "CBLOL Split 1 2020"]')
        dropDown.click()
        sleep(5)

        self.html = self.driver.page_source
        self.driver.close()
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for tr in resp.xpath('(//tbody)[2]/tr'):
            yield {
                'Name': tr.xpath(".//td/a/text()").get(),
                'Season': tr.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get(),
                'Region': tr.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").get(),
                'Games': tr.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").get(),
                'winRate': tr.xpath(".//td[5]/text()").get()
                    
            }
```

OUTPUT:

```
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'Flamengo eSports', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '61.9%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'FURIA Uppercut', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '52.4%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'INTZ e-Sports', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '38.1%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'KaBuM! e-Sports', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '52.4%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'paiN Gaming', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '47.6%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'Prodigy Esports', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '52.4%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'Redemption POA', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '28.6%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://gol.gg/teams/list/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-CBLOL%20Split%201%202020/>
{'Name': 'Vivo Keyd', 'Season': 'S10', 'Region': 'BR', 'Games': '21', 'winRate': '66.7%'}
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-08-04 13:59:37 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 490,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1078,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.668237,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 4, 7, 59, 37, 58803),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 278,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'item_scraped_count': 8,
```

Comment: If it works , click the tick mark left hand  side of my answer   to help others as the community rule.